# XSLT - Don't display a tag if value = "000000"

Tags: xml, xslt, idoc

I am converting a SAP IDOC into a more human readable XML format.

I have the below XSLT which hides empty values (CHARG, VFDAT)

```
<Product>
        <OrderLineNo><xsl:value-of select="VGPOS"/></OrderLineNo>
        <ProductDescription><xsl:value-of select="ARKTX"/></ProductDescription>
        <ProductCode><xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/></ProductCode>
        <xsl:if test="EAN11">
            <Barcode><xsl:value-of select="EAN11"/></Barcode>
        </xsl:if>
        <QuantityDelivered><xsl:value-of select="LFIMG"/></QuantityDelivered>
        <SalesUnit><xsl:value-of select="VRKME"/></SalesUnit>
        <xsl:if test="CHARG">
            <Batch><xsl:value-of select="CHARG"/></Batch>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="VFDAT">
            <ExpiryDate><xsl:value-of select="VFDAT"/></ExpiryDate>
        </xsl:if>
    </Product>
```

This gets the below XML output, which hides VFDAT and EAN11 where it doesn't exist in the source XML document.

I also want to hide VFDAT when the value < 1.

How would I do this?

```
<Product>
 <OrderLineNo>000010</OrderLineNo>
 <ProductDescription>BARBER'S CATALOGUE</ProductDescription>
 <ProductCode>000000000030199850</ProductCode>
 <QuantityDelivered>20.000</QuantityDelivered>
 <SalesUnit>EA</SalesUnit>
 <ExpiryDate>00000000</ExpiryDate>
</Product>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it as,

If you are using XSLT 2.0 then following should work,

```
<xsl:if test="VFDAT gt 0">
    <ExpiryDate><xsl:value-of select="VFDAT"/></ExpiryDate>
</xsl:if>
```

If XSLT 1.0,

```
<xsl:if test="VFDAT &gt; 0">
    <ExpiryDate><xsl:value-of select="VFDAT"/></ExpiryDate>
</xsl:if>
```

or

```
<xsl:if test="VFDAT > 0">
    <ExpiryDate><xsl:value-of select="VFDAT"/></ExpiryDate>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: @Jackulus are you using xslt 1.0 or 2.0? Updated my answer back. Please accept if that helped :)

Comment: VFDAT > 0 seems to work for me, i'll do some additional testing. Thank you!

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but my header says:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>

Comment: Does that answer the question?

Comment: Its 2.0, Please check with gt and accpet answer if helped.

Comment: Only 'VFDAT > 0' works.

I get a failed to transform message otherwise.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. Strange that > works even on http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

Comment: The fact that your stylesheet says version="2.0" does not mean that your XSLT processor is an XSLT 2.0 processor.